# Euler's function and primorial

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function, primorial

I study about primorial.

I found some property in wiki; [Applications and properties] in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial.
That is "Here For each primorial n, the fraction $\frac{\phi(n)}{n}$ is smaller than it for any lesser integer, where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function."

Actually I want to obtain the proposition:
For $m<p_{n}\sharp$, then $\frac{\phi(p_{n}\sharp)}{p_{n}\sharp}<\frac{\phi(m)}{m}$ where positive integer $n$, $m$ and $\phi$ is Euler's function .

The problem is:

(1) Are wiki's argue and the proposition what I want same?

(2-1) If same, Where from the wiki's argue?

(2-2) If not same, is there any clue for the proposition?

Comment: As a first step, note that $$\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}$$ does not change its value, if we replace $\ n\ $ by its radical, so we can assume that $\ n\ $ is squarefree.

Comment: Is that mean $\frac{\phi(n)}{n}=\frac{\phi(rad(n))}{rad(n)}$?

Comment: Correct, and if we only consider squarefree numbers, the statement becomes already more clear. But still the proof is not trivial.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I adjust $m$ and $n$. Please review the proposition what I want.

Comment: The second step is to start with an arbitary squarefree number and compare the value of the fraction with the value we get by replacing the number by the primorial with the same number of prime factors.

Comment: I understand what you mean! Thanks. Happy new year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that if $p_i\mid m$ for all $1\le i \le n$, then $m\ge \prod_{i=1}^n(p_i)=p_n\#$. So if we choose $m<p_n\#$, then there must be one or more values of $i$ such that $p_i\not\mid m$.

Let us divide the set of the first $n$ prime numbers $\{p_n\}$ into two subsets: $\{p_j\}$ such that $p_j\not\mid m$ and $\{p_k\}$ such that $p_k\mid m$. Now we can say  $$p_n\#=\prod(p_j)\prod(p_k)\\ \frac{\phi(p_n\#)}{p_n\#}=\prod\frac{p_j-1}{p_j}\prod\frac{p_k-1}{p_k}$$
Also, $$m=\prod (p_k)^{a_k} \\ \frac{\phi(m)}{m}=\prod\frac{p_k^{a_k-1}(p_k-1)}{(p_k)^{a_k}}=\prod\frac{p_k-1}{p_k}$$
Substituting the last result in the first, we see $$\frac{\phi(p_n\#)}{p_n\#}=\prod\frac{p_j-1}{p_j}\frac{\phi(m)}{m}$$
We know there is at least one term in the product over the index $j$, and that for every such term $\frac{p_j-1}{p_j}<1$

Hence we can say that for $m<p_n\#$, $$\frac{\phi(p_n\#)}{p_n\#}<\frac{\phi(m)}{m}$$

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I proved myself. But your prove is more simple and easy. I'll consider your prove by adding some details in my paper.